# Making a reverse list

Tags: prolog

I have the following codes. Trying to make a reverse list. but it doesnt work.

```
reverse([],[H|T]).
reverse([H|T],Z) :- reverse(T,[H|Z]).
```

I run this in prolog and I get this:

```
1 ?- trace, reverse([1,2,3],X).
   Call: (7) reverse([1, 2, 3], _G396) ? creep
   Call: (8) reverse([2, 3], [1|_G396]) ? creep
   Call: (9) reverse([3], [2, 1|_G396]) ? creep
   Call: (10) reverse([], [3, 2, 1|_G396]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) reverse([], [3, 2, 1|_G396]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) reverse([3], [2, 1|_G396]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) reverse([2, 3], [1|_G396]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) reverse([1, 2, 3], _G396) ? creep
true.
```

this should give me [3,2,1], instead of [1,2,3]. what is going wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right. What you need is an "accumulator" which collects the result so far and passes it to the return variable at the end of the recursion:

```
reverse([],Z,Z).
reverse([H|T],Z,Acc) :- reverse(T,Z,[H|Acc]).
```

Otherwise the reversed list is forgotten as the function returns from the recursive calls. You need to instantiate the accumulator with an empty list when you call `reverse/3`:

```
?- reverse([1,2,3],X,[]).
```

If you do the trace you will see that the second argument does not get instantiated until your original list is empty.

Comment: @scarface Are you sure? If it isn't doing anything, you should leave it out completely and see what happens.

Comment: @scarface BTW, this is a textbook implementation of `reverse` using an implementation. See also, for example, the [SWI-Prolog library implementaton](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#reverse/2).

Comment: In fact, I see that it needs to be there. I would like to know the explanation how is it possible that when reverse([],Z,Z) is called, the value of accumulator is saved in the middle even if your recursion goes out of the depth. I do not understand why Acc fades away bit after bit while going out of the depth of recursion and the Z is "assigned" in the last call and then it stays assigned even when we go out from the depth of recursion.

Comment: And also what how can I imagine what the first lines does? I do not really get it.

Comment: @scarface As said before, this is textbook stuff, so get a textbook and read it. I would recommend "The Art of Prolog" by Sterling and Shapiro, for example, even though I suspect this might also be explained online in a textbook like "Learn Prolog Now!". Or, just ask another question: you can link this question and the answers, explain what is not clear to you, and ask more specifically!

Comment: @scarface Shortly, if you understand how unification works, you should understand why this predicate defines a list reversal.

Comment: Okay, Boris. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 7):

When a list is empty, its reverse is empty.
So

```
reverse([], []).
```

In another case, you append the first element of the list at the end of the revese of the rest of the list. so :

```
reverse([H|T],Z) :-
    reverse(T,Z1),
    append(Z1, [H], Z).
```